# Why Homestead is running apache by default even if not specified?

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have a Homestead VM with multiple nginx sites and a couple of apache sites too, everything configured through the Homestead.yaml file (short example below):

```
sites:

- map: site1.local
  to: /home/vagrant/site1
  php: "7.1"
  #type: "apache  <= (commented on purpose, not an error)

- map: site2.local
  to: /home/vagrant/site2
  php: "7.1"
```

I've been working turning On and Off the `type: "apache"` setting so the VM starts running apache (instead of nginx) or not, depending on the site that I need to work on at the specific moment.

My Issue now is that, after upgrading Vagrant and Homestead, it always keeps starting apache by default, no matter if it is specified or not, ALWAYS!; so everytime I start the machine, I need to ssh-it and `flip` the server.

I even tried using the services config directive as follows, without luck:

```
services:
    - enabled:
        - "nginx"
    - disabled:
        - "apache2"
```

Any thoughts? Please help!

Versions I am using:

```
Vagrant 2.2.7
Homestead 10.8.0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar issue. It turned out that I needed to log in the VM through SSH, and run the following command:

```
sudo systemctl enable nginx.service
```

When you look at restart-webserver.sh in the Homestead scripts directory, you will see that it verifies whether nginx is enabled, otherwise it always tries to restart Apache.

Answer (score 0):

There is a file where you can run your custom scripts right after homestead  provisioning scripts

```
C:\Users\...\Homestead\after.sh
```

add the following lines there

```
sudo systemctl disable apache2
sudo systemctl enable nginx.service
```

run

```
vagrant provision
```

now, to test the setup, run

```
vagrant halt
```

and then

```
vagrant up
```